# Where is the best place to put database ids on the client-side?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, client-side

I'm serving up a page using ASP.Net.  I have Add/Edit/Delete functionality of controls I've added dynamically using jQuery on a page, some of which have related records in a database.  Where is the best place to put the id (primary key) for these, an attribute, data-*, jQuery.data()?  Should I be concerned if the Id is visible client-side?

Comment: what platform is this? php, asp.net, ect?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Best practice is to use [jQuery.data()](http://api.jquery.com/data/), as this follows the [HTML5 standard for such information](http://ejohn.org/blog/html-5-data-attributes/).

Answer (score 6):

It's good practice to encrypt the ID of the record on the client side to ensure the security of your database. Usually a hidden field will do the trick.

This way, the user only sees the encrypted id upon viewing the source. The script being called then uses the key used to encrypt to retrieve the record identifier server side and manipulate data as needed.

Answer (score 2):

Firstly do *not* use the direct database ID.  You will be tied to directly to one version of one table's Primary Key.  Instead create a second column, using UUID to be the place holder of primary key

for example

```
tbl_person
 person_id INT PRIMARY KEY
 person_uuid VARCHAR(64)
 name VARCHAR(128)
```

But to answer the actual question, I suggest you use an attribute of the appropriate element, proabbly id

```
<tr><td id="1234-5678">Paul </td></tr>
```

(edit to get code formatting right)

Comment: I would argue that a web-page transaction is short lived, and the expectation that the primary key for a record will not change between actions is a valid one.  While a UUID approach is valid under certain circumstances, I think keeping things simpler until it is a requirement is better.

Comment: +1 It's also a safety risk to send data back according to an id that comes from the browser. With a bit of firebug a person can access other people data if the server doesn't restrict that with a session mechanizm.

Answer (score 1):

You can add your own attribute to an element (e.g `my-attr="92"`), you can use a hidden input field with the value set to the id (`<input type="hidden" value="92" />`), or you can just use the `id` attribute (e.g `id="db-92"`).

I don't think it really matters which method you use, whatever best suits.

Comment: I create my own attributes all the time, and think this is a great way to go! Except of course, that it won't validate :)

Comment: Much better to follow the standards and use `data` attributes: http://ejohn.org/blog/html-5-data-attributes/ (via the jQuery.data API).

Comment: @Martijn: but what about browsers that don't support HTML5?

Comment: It'll still work because those browsers ignore these attributes but still allow access to these attributes; the data attributes do not require special support in the browser.

Answer (score 1):

You should **Never** put this on your client. Since you will inevitably go back through your server to get to the data at most you should put some form of key (like dsource = 'db3' as an attribute or in a hidden field..) and then do some manner of look-up in the server process.

Comment: Why not exactly? I don't see why it's so bad to put <element class="{object_id: 9}"></element> within the HTML, it's not exactly a security risk if you are verifying the ownership of the object.

Comment: I don't see where _verification of the ownership_ is set as a condition of the OP. Even then such information should be kept compartmentalized. A user (on a browser) has no need to know such information. (even if it is obscured in the mark-up, IMHO, it is still a security risk)

Comment: @Homer, I see that you have edited the question since my original answer. My answer is especially true given that you are using asp.net. weather you are using _page methods, _callbacks or web services_ on the server there is nothing to be gained by sending the db id to the client, it should be easily accessible on the server. If you find you must send something to the client, then make it a key of some kind and not the actual id.

Comment: Without a `Postback` and `ViewState`, how would it be accessible on the server?  For example, without the id on the client side, how does the server know which record to delete based on an `<a>` click?

Comment: hmmmm... in your original (and revised) post you ask `Where is the best place to put the database id?` Which I took to be the ID of the database (db name), now it sounds like you are referring to a "record id". If this is the case then I misunderstood your meaning and would concur that for a record id (primary key) that the _best practice_ is to add a custom attribute to your anchor tag like `<a id="deleteButton" pkey="1" onclick="deleteItem();">click to delete</a>`

Comment: Correct, I did not mean database name. I meant record id (primary key).  I'll fix that.  Thanks!

Comment: I agree with Cos - it's a security risk. And it's often used. Example usage: Wherever you have a primary key in the browser it's quite possible that entering a different id there will allow access to other element's or user's data. Recently seen in some government sites with citizens' personal data in my country.

Answer (score 1):

I always use the jQuery metadata library, which essentially is the $().data() functionality enclosed within the class (or any other) attribute of the object.

Find the jQuery metadata plugin [here](http://plugins.jquery.com/project/metadata): "This plugin is capable of extracting metadata from classes, random attributes, child elements and HTML5 data-* attributes."

So you can do stuff like this:

```
<tr><td>Dave Jones</td><td><input class="delete_person {person_id: 90}" type="button" value="Delete this guy" /></tr>
```

then with jQuery:

```
$('.delete_person.').click(function() { 
    // delete person 
    $.post('/controller/delete_person', {person_id: $(this).metadata().person_id},  
    function() {
     // the person was deleted
    }
});
```

Hope that helps!

Comment: Why not use the jQuery native .data API?